# Viewing "alphabetical filters" on a small screen

Tags: paraview

The Paraview "Alphabetical Filters" menu appears to be bigger than my laptop screen.

When I open the menu, a list of filters covers my entire screen (as has happened when I've used Paraview previously on other, larger, screens). I see filters listed alphabetically. They start at "AMR connectivity" on the upper-left corner of the screen, but terminate with "Tube" at the bottom right, with filters U through Z out of sight.

How can I access the full set of filters on this laptop?

This is Paraview 5.4.1 64-bit on lubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

There is a dedicated option for this, but only with ParaView >= 5.5.0

- Edit->Settings->Show advanced options (cogwheel)
- General->Force Single Column Filter Menu

Answer (score 0):

In Paraview 5.4, the menu text size can be reduced, allowing more options to fit on the screen:

- edit > settings > general > GUI font > override font > set font size to 8

This fix works down to a 14" or 15" screen, provided the user is comfortable reading small text.